# Spring Cloud Dataflow - Composite Task Runner Issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I'm exploring all the features of Spring Cloud Dataflow for our project. Currently I'm doing all development locally(No docker, Cloudfoundry & Kubernates)
Currently I have created 2 Spring Batch Jobs using Spring Boot 3 & Spring Batch 5.

- Job 1 - Create a CSV file
- Job 2 - Read the CSV and insert data to DB

Since the current version of SCDF(2.10.3) doesn't support Spring Boot3, I have used 2.11.0-RC1 version for now as its only for local development.

I have created a Spring Boot application with version 2.7.14 (Same as the one used by SCDF 2.11.0-RC1). And Using own DB, I had successfully started the server on a port 7070 (instead of default 9393). Similarly I have started Skipper server as well(on a different port - 7500). And the 2 jobs were registered and the task was executed manually and it was successful.

Now I tried a composite task. But it does not run. Here is my server code.

###### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>scdfdemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>scdfdemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0-RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0-RC1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0-RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-skipper</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0-RC1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**The only Java code**

```
package com.demo.test.scdfdemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.EnableDataFlowServer;
import org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration;
@EnableDataFlowServer
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ScdfdemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ScdfdemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=7070

spring.main.cloud-platform=NONE
spring.profiles.active=cloud

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/scdfdemo
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

### SCDF Configurations
spring.cloud.dataflow.features.schedules-enabled=true
spring.cloud.dataflow.features.streams-enabled=true
spring.cloud.dataflow.features.tasks-enabled=true

spring.cloud.skipper.client.server-uri=http://localhost:7500/api

#spring.cloud.dataflow.task.composedtaskrunner.uri=http://localhost:7070
```

In the UI, I registered 2 apps and ran successfully. When I create a composite task(name :invoice-composed) with 2 tasks added, and if I open the task list it shows the composite job and the 2 sub jobs without any issues. And when I open the launch screen of composed task it shows UI properly without any error. But if we check log, it shows below exception

```
[2m2023-09-15 12:47:53.044[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m3004[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.c.d.a.t.AggregateExecutionSupport   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cannot find AppRegistration for invoice-composed
[2m2023-09-15 12:47:53.073[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m3004[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.s.c.d.a.t.AggregateExecutionSupport   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cannot find AppRegistration for invoice-composed
[2m2023-09-15 12:47:59.031[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m3004[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-8][0;39m [36mo.s.c.d.a.t.AggregateExecutionSupport   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cannot find AppRegistration for invoice-composed
[2m2023-09-15 12:47:59.176[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m3004[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.c.d.a.t.AggregateExecutionSupport   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cannot find AppRegistration for invoice-composed
[2m2023-09-15 12:47:59.294[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m3004[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.c.d.a.t.AggregateExecutionSupport   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cannot find AppRegistration for invoice-composed
[2m2023-09-15 12:47:59.533[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m3004[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-9][0;39m [36mApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Failed to retrieve properties for resource org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-task-runner:jar:2.11.0-RC1 because of UnknownHostException: repo.maven.apache.org
```

**Why is it trying to connect to remote maven repo? I'm behind a proxy. So it wont get connected. Can we point to local repo directory? If so how?**

Since there was no error in log, I launched the composite task and it showed error. Got below NullPointerException in logs.

```
[2m2023-09-15 12:49:13.556[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m3004[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.c.d.a.t.AggregateExecutionSupport   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cannot find AppRegistration for invoice-composed
[2m2023-09-15 12:49:13.580[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m3004[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-7070-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.c.d.s.c.RestControllerAdvice        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Caught exception while handling a request

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.core.dsl.TaskApp.getLabel()" is null
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionInfoService.composedTaskChildNames(DefaultTaskExecutionInfoService.java:256) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.11.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService.executeTask(DefaultTaskExecutionService.java:418) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.11.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$422cda43.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.11.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9bd23d3b.executeTask(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.11.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.controller.TaskExecutionController.launchBoot3(TaskExecutionController.java:246) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.11.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:768) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I even tried to add composite task runner dependency in pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-task-runner</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

But then the server itself doesn't start, throwing ClassNotFoundException.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.composedtaskrunner.support.CfServiceBindingPropertySourceInitializer
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:449)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:431)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:267)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:245)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.demo.test.scdfdemo.ScdfdemoApplication.main(ScdfdemoApplication.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.composedtaskrunner.support.CfServiceBindingPropertySourceInitializer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:442)
    ... 7 more
```

I Googled, but could not find which extra dependency is required here. Can someone help?

Comment: It is trying to retrieve available properties for CTR so that it can display them in the UI.   This comes from the maven repository.  Here are the instructions on setting dataflow to use a private repository: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_configure_maven_properties

You shouldn't need the to add CTR to your dataflow POM file.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I had to give the organization's repo URL. But wondering why it needs to download the runner at runtime rather than taking dependencies defined from pom.xml, especially when I have created as a Spring Boot app and starting the server.

Comment: Composed Task Runner is a separate Task/Batch Application that is designed to be launched by SCDF like any Task but the definition describes a flow of tasks to orchestrate.